# What happened to Jojo after installing the Shield in Love Alarm

Tags: character, love-alarm

I recently watched season 1 of Love Alarm. Then first season ended up with a lot of questions in viewers' mind. The question that I genuinely wanted to get answered was :

> Why  did  Kim   Jojo  break  up  with  Sun  Oh?

Was it because she installed the SHIELD, and why did she install it in the first place?

I thought that things will get cleared in Season 2, so proceeded to watch it as well. But nothing came out. The question still remains unanswered.

Does someone know the answer as to why Jojo did so?